# Oracle XE service FAILED, No me deja instalar oracle xe 11g

Tags: oracle, servicio, proceso

en esta ocasión tengo un problema con la instalación de ORACLE XE service instance al lado dice FAILED, cabe destacar que lo pude instalar sin ningun problema, pero como tuve un problema tambien, lo desinstalé, pero ahora me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que creen que pueda estar pasando?

Comment: al iniciar el instalador te dice que el genera un arcivo de `log` en la carpeta `appdata` del usuario si podrias subir el error especifico listado ahi podriamos ayudarte mejor ya que el error listado en la gui es muy global, pero el el log te especifica en que parte exactamente fallo.

Comment: Estoy en appdata pero en cual de las 3 carpetas exactamente me lo genera?

Comment: perdon es database xe se encuentra en `oraInventory/logs/installActions<timestamp>.log` dentro de tu `ORACLE_HOME` o carpeta de instalacion del oracle!

Comment: Como? si no puedo instalar oracle...

Comment: sorry estoy en la version de app no me aparesian las imagenes lo que te dice es que ya existe una instancia de oracle xe en ejecucion debes borrar la carpeta de la instalacion vieja o sus registro dentro de regedit!